# default constructor chaining

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

**(true or false)If the first statement of a constructor you write is not a call on another constructor, a default constructor call in inserted.**

The answer to this question is true.
then I tried and created some chained constructors.

```
public class Temp {
     // default constructor 1
    Temp()
    {
        System.out.println("default");
    }

    // parameterized constructor 2
    Temp(int x)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        new Temp(8);
    }
}
```

output:

```
8
```

"default" was not printed. So I think the default constructor was not being called. The answer should be false. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: It's **true**, however the default constructor called is the `super()` constructor. Here that would be `Object`. Not `Temp`. Also, you have no default constructor. You have a no-arg constructor. If you add any constructors at all, then you get no default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

From [Java SE 8 Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

So `a default constructor call in inserted.`, but it's default constructor of your super class (in this case: `Object`) instead of your being declared class.